# Quantstart `osMaxPos` source code second typo error is testified?

Tags: r, quantstrat

I looked into `osMaxPos` just trying to understand quantstrat a little better, however, there are two lines of codes confused me, I think they are typo errors.

source code can be found at [this link](https://github.com/R-Finance/quantstrat/blob/master/R/osFUNs.R) Briefly, the two typo errors are: 1. source code line 212 `if(orderqty+pos>PosLimit[,"MaxPos"]) orderqty <- PosLimit[,"MinPos"]-pos`, but I think authors intended it to be `if (orderqty+pos < PosLimit[, "MinPos"]) orderqty <- PosLimit[,"MinPos"]-pos`; 2. source code line 226 is `orderqty <- pos`, but I think the code was intended to be `orderqty <- -pos`

There may be answers to this question at [R-Forge tracker](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6306&group_id=316&atid=1269) in a near future. If not, I hope someone may help me through stackoverflow. I tried to testify the second typo error through the following simple example.

This example takes part of the source code and run through some fake data to demonstrate that the second typo error is really there. But I am new to trading and R, so I could be totally wrong. Could someone help me have a look, thanks.

```
# #### run a simplifed strategy to get values for pos and PosLimit
# portfolio <- "test"
# symbol <- "JQR_DAY"
# timestamp <- as.Date("2013-09-09")
# # get position quantity of timestamp
# pos <- getPosQty(portfolio, symbol, timestamp)
# # get positionlimits on timestamp
# PosLimit <- getPosLimit(portfolio, symbol, timestamp)


#### to make this example reproducible, I created pos and PosLimit values as following: 
pos <- -4000
PosLimit <- xts(t(c(4000, 4, -4000, 4)), order.by = as.Date("2000-09-09"))
colnames(PosLimit) <- c("MaxPos", "LongLevels", "MinPos", "ShortLevels")

orderside <- "short" # existing positions are shorting
ruletype <- "risk" # ruletype is "risk"

# senario1:  flatten all short positions
# orderqty <- "all" 
# in the end, orderqty will be 4000 to be able to close all short positions

# senario2: orderqty is not enough to close all short positions
# orderqty <- 2000  # orderqty will be finally set as 2000

# senario3: orderqty is more than enough to close all short positions
orderqty <- 5000  # orderqty should be finally set as 4000, 
                  # but it turns out to be -4000

# if using orderqty <- -pos, orderqty will be 4000


####################################################################
#### simplified code to perform buy_cover_short
####################################################################
# if orderside is short and orderqty > 0 to exit shorting
# if orderqty == "all", orderqty > 0 is true
if (orderqty > 0 & orderside == "short") {
    # orderside == "short" suggests pos < 0

    # if ruletype = risk
    if (ruletype == "risk") {

        # if orderqty = all
        if (orderqty == "all") 

            # return -pos 
            orderqty <- (-1 * pos) 
        # meaning exit all shorting positions

        # if orderqty != all, return orderqty itself
        # only exit order quantity of short positions
        else orderqty <- orderqty
    }

    # if orderqty > 0 but orderqty < |pos|
    if ((orderqty + pos) <= 0) {

        # return orderqty itself
        # meaning leaving some shorting position alive
        orderqty <- orderqty
    }

    # if orderqty + pos > 0
    # meaning orderqty > -pos
    # meaning orderqty > |pos|
    else {

        # it is a typo error ??????????????????? 
        #flatten position, don't cross through zero
        orderqty <- pos # orderqty <- -pos

    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the right venue for this type of question. Very few people are going to know the answer, because it's a trading logic question, not a programming question. You should ask on the R-Forge tracker.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the actual source code has (hopefully helpful) comments. So you should be looking at that instead of the source code printed to the R console.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua. Both of your suggestions are very helpful. I will do that.

Comment: I posted this question in R-forge tracker. https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6306&group_id=316&atid=1269

Comment: @Joshua Urich I tried to testify whether the second error is really there through the example I pasted above

Comment: this question is answered by Joshua Urich and Brian Peterson at R-forge tracker https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6306&group_id=316&atid=1269